# codeigniter with MVC pattern

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am working on ci and when i am going to delete my data then i want to generate a confirm message box on click delete link and my code is this.

**view.php**

id);?>">Delete

**controller.php**

function delete($id)
    {
        $this->include_user->delete($id);
        redirect(site_url('admin_controller/fetch'));
    }

**Model.php**

function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->delete("user",array('id' => $id));
    }

Comment: either you want to show confirmation message that user really want to delete, or success message that your record is deleted successfully?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show confirmation message that either user really want to delete, then you can use jquery confirm box plugin and when click on delete anchor then on delete show the confirm box.

e.g: in js code

```
jConfirm('Do you really want to delete?', 'Delete Confirmation', function(r) {
  if (r == true) {
  }
}
```

In my case I am using jquery confirm box.

And in case if you want to show success message then you can send back a flag when record is deleted to controller, then checking the flag, if successfully record is deleted then pas success message to your message controller or wise failure message.